# Driving in Dusseldorf´s low emission zone

Tags: germany, car-rentals, automobiles, dusseldorf, cologne

I will rent a car in France and travel to Dusseldorf and Cologne. Do I need a emission sticker to enter those cities? If so, there is a physical store where I can buy it, instead of buying it online? How long does it take to get the sticker bought through the store?

Regards
Michael

Comment: Shouldn’t you get the emission sticker from the car rental company?

Comment: I doubt that a french rental car agency cares about german emission zones. So the probability is quite low, that their cars have the appropriate stickers.

Comment: I know that in Munich they had stickers to drive in Austria, but that is just one kind of sticker for a whole (and directly neighbouring) country. You need different stickers for every city in Germany, so that car rental place in France would need a huge number of different ones.

Comment: @gnasher729 That is not correct. The stickers for Austria were probably toll stickers. In Germany, this is about emission classes and it's the same sticker for all of Germany. What differs between cities is whether they have an emission control zone at all (for which you'd need a sticker that proves your car fulfills the required standards).

Comment: Where can I buy this sticker?

Answer (score 10):

You do need an emission sticker for the inner parts of both cities. Here are links to maps showing the zone for [Düsseldorf](https://www.duesseldorf.de/fileadmin/Amt33/strassenverkehrsamt/pdf/umweltzone_duesseldorf_2013.pdf) and [Cologne (Köln)](https://www.stadt-koeln.de/mediaasset/content/pdf57/karte_umweltzone_erweiterung_2012.pdf) to see if your destination is part of the zone. If these links become invalid, just use Google's picture search for "Umweltzone [name of city]" and you should get decent results.

First I'd ask the car rental company beforehand whether they have cars which got the sticker already. If that's not the case, you'll have to buy one yourself (~ 5 Euros)

You can get the sticker at one of the official inspection authorities. These are named DEKRA, GTÜ, TÜV and KÜS. My suggestion would be to search Google Maps for these and choose one that is conveniently on your planned route. They're usually in industrial areas of towns. Mind the opening times, and make sure you know where the car's registration documents are. It should only take a few minutes on location.

Comment: If you think this is the best answer, wait 1 day for any further answers, and then click on the tick beside it.